# Find a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ that satisfies the following

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a full rank $m\times n$ matrix.

a) Assuming that $m<n$, find a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with smallest 2-norm that solves $Ax = b$.

b) Assuming $m>n$, find a vector $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that minimizes $\lvert Ax - b \vert$

The solution to part b) can be done using Grammian Matrices.  IIRC, I believe the minimizer, $\bar{x}$, is $\bar{x} = (A^TA)^{-1}(A^Tb)$.

Part a has thrown me for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If $n>m$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is full rank, then its kernel has dimension $n-m$ and the set $S$ of solutions to $Ax=b$ will be an affine subspace that looks like:

$$S=\ker(A)+x_p,$$

where $x_p$ is any particular solution to $Ax=b$. So what you really want to find is the element $x \in S$ that minimizes $\min\{\lVert x \rVert \, ; \, x \in S\}$.

You can think of this in many ways, say orthogonally projecting the origin onto $S$, or finding the convex projection of the origin onto $S$. One way to do this would be to orthogonally project $-x_p$ onto $\ker(A)$, and then finally translate the result by $+x_p$.